# The most efficient way to check if all values in a row are the same or are NA

Tags: r, dplyr, filter, data.table, row

I want to check if all values in each row are the same, but, `NA` should be ignored
MWE:

```
library(data.table)
DT=data.table(v1=c(1,2,3),v2=c(1,3,3), v3=c(NA,2,3))

DT
   v1 v2 v3
1:  1  1 NA
2:  2  3  2
3:  3  3  3

desired=c(T,F,T)

desired
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: `rowMeans(as.matrix(DT) == unlist(DT[, 1]), na.rm = TRUE)==1`???

Comment: this is not efficient, it creates a matrix, an unlist a column, i.e. needs lots of memory.

Comment: Actually it makes more than one matrix.

Comment: What about `apply(DT, 1, function(x) fifelse(length(unique(x[!is.na(x)])) == 1, TRUE,FALSE ))` ?

Comment: Not really, `unique` is very complicated function. and every time a `vectorized` function is nested inside another one a copy of data is made which means `vectorization` is not as ideal as it is assumed.

Comment: try `apply(DT, 1, \(x)length(table(x))==1)`. If not, You could write your own function, a short circuited for loop  and iterate through each row

Answer (score 7):

I get an efficient idea

```
v1 = do.call(pmin, c(DT, na.rm = TRUE))
v2 = do.call(pmax, c(DT, na.rm = TRUE))
v1 == v2
```

Comment: This is a good solution, for my data with dim 3M x 303 it takes about 18 seconds, although I was wishing for a solution below 1 second, however, I guess this should be ok.