# The most efficient way to check if all values in a row are the same or are missing

Tags: r, dplyr, filter, data.table, julia

I originally asked this question in `data.table` forum, and received some good answers but I hope to find a less-than-a-sec solution (real data dims 3M x 303)

The [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70735936/the-most-efficient-way-to-check-if-all-values-in-a-row-are-the-same-or-are-na) to my post in R community, and MWE in julia (using DataFrames.jl if I am using wrong packages please let me know)

```
julia> using DataFrames

julia> df = DataFrame(v1 = [1.0,2.1,3.0], v2 = [1,3,3], v3 = [missing,2.1,3.0])
3×3 DataFrame
 Row │ v1       v2     v3
     │ Float64  Int64  Float64?
─────┼───────────────────────────
   1 │     1.0      1  missing
   2 │     2.1      3        2.1
   3 │     3.0      3        3.0

julia> desired = [true,false,true]
3-element Vector{Bool}:
 1
 0
 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another update on this, Now I am able to reduce the time to under a second (in fact under 0.5 second) using `InMemoryDatasets`, thanks to this [discussion](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/ann-a-new-lightning-fast-package-for-data-manipulation-in-pure-julia/78197/42) in Julia lang discourse.

```
julia> using InMemoryDatasets
julia> df = Dataset(df)
julia> f(x,y) = ismissing(x) || ismissing(y) ? true : x == y
julia> byrow(df, isless, [:v1, :v2, :v3], with = byrow(df, coalesce, :), lt = f)
```

## Update

with the new update from the discourse discussion I am able to almost half the previous insane record :D, i.e. 0.27 (**Julia community really loves SPEED**)

```
julia> byrow(df, issorted, [:v1, :v2, :v3], lt = !f)
```

Answer (score 9):

In Julia using a matrix for such operation, similarly to R, is also natural:

```
julia> using BenchmarkTools

julia> function helper(x)
           nonempty = false
           local fv
           for v in x
               if !ismissing(v)
                   if nonempty
                       v == fv || return false
                   else
                       fv = v
                       nonempty = true
                   end
               end
           end
           return true
       end
helper (generic function with 1 method)

julia> mat = rand([1, 2, missing], 3_000_000, 303);

julia> @benchmark helper.(eachrow($mat))
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 34 samples with 1 evaluation.
 Range (min … max):  139.440 ms … 154.628 ms  ┊ GC (min … max): 5.74% … 5.15%
 Time  (median):     147.890 ms               ┊ GC (median):    5.27%        
 Time  (mean ± σ):   147.876 ms ±   3.114 ms  ┊ GC (mean ± σ):  5.23% ± 0.95%

                    ▃    ▃   ▃  ▃  ██ ▃
  ▇▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▇▁▁▁▁▁▁▁█▁▁▁▁█▇▇▇█▁▁█▇▁██▇█▁▇▁▇▇▁▇▇▁▇▁▇▇▇▁▁▁▁▇▁▁▁▁▇ ▁
  139 ms           Histogram: frequency by time          155 ms <

 Memory estimate: 114.80 MiB, allocs estimate: 6.
```

The operation can be also done in DataFrames.jl, here is an example how to do it:

```
julia> function helper2(x, i)
           nonempty = false
           local fv
           for v in x
               vv = v[i]
               if !ismissing(vv)
                   if nonempty
                       vv == fv || return false
                   else
                       fv = vv
                       nonempty = true
                   end
               end
           end
           return true
       end
helper2 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> df = DataFrame(mat, :auto, copycols=false); # copycols to avoid copying as data is large

julia> @benchmark helper2.(Ref(identity.(eachcol($df))), 1:nrow($df))
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 46 samples with 1 evaluation.
 Range (min … max):  105.265 ms … 123.345 ms  ┊ GC (min … max): 0.00% … 0.00%
 Time  (median):     110.682 ms               ┊ GC (median):    0.00%
 Time  (mean ± σ):   110.581 ms ±   2.692 ms  ┊ GC (mean ± σ):  0.00% ± 0.00%

                ▄ ▂ ▄█▂
  ▄▁▁▄▄▁▁▆▄▁▁▁▆▆█▄█▆███▄▄▁█▄▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▄▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▄ ▁
  105 ms           Histogram: frequency by time          123 ms <

 Memory estimate: 385.28 KiB, allocs estimate: 15.
```

(if anything in the code is not clear please let me know and I can explain)

---

#### EDIT

If you a small union of unique `eltypes` do:

```
helper2.(Ref(collect(Union{unique(typeof.(eachcol(df)))...}, eachcol(df))), 1:nrow(df))
```

If `Union{unique(typeof.(eachcol(df)))...}` is not a small collection then another solution would be better so please comment if this is good enough for you.

Comment: As I mentioned above the data structure isn't really a matrix, it is a non-homogeneous list of vectors (abstractvector of vectors in julian terminology), MWE is just to illustrate the problem.

Comment: do you have a `3_000_000` element vector of `303` element vectors or a `303` element vector of `3_000_000` element vectors? In the first case use the first solution. In the second case use the second one (a syntax would need to be minimally changed but in general the same pattern should be used). If you update your question with a concrete data structure you use I will be able to update my answer.

Comment: It is a data frame with 3M rows and I need this for about 303 columns of it, the columns are either integers, floats, strings. strings are not involved for this problem. so a vector with `ncol` and each one has about 3M elements.

Comment: if it is a `DataFrame` then you have a solution for it already in my answer.

Comment: your second function took about 78 seconds.

Comment: side note, there are about 1G allocations for your code

Comment: This signals that there is a significant heterogenity in your source columns `eltype`. This is something that was not present in your original question. Since you are asking for "most efficient" code the exact characteristic of data matters a lot - I optimized the code for data you shared. I would recommend you to update your question with the data for which you want to get the most efficient code. Then I can update my answer.

Comment: Could you explain what the `identity.()` call in the last benchmark is doing, is it just an alternate way of doing a `collect`? Also, maybe I'm misunderstanding something, but the second example seems to be checking all values in a *column* are the same or missing, not row.

Comment: Updated the question, columns are mostly integers but there are some floats here & there

Comment: `identity.()` does `eltype` reduction - and this is a crucial issue in this problem. The second code works rowwise - note that I index it by `i`.

Comment: I have updated the answer for the case of small union mixing floats and ints. On my computer it runs in around 116.094 ms.

Comment: The updated code took 12 secs.

Comment: @BogumiłKamiński FYI, based on my discussion with OP, the dataset has 30-70% rows with identical values. I guess that's the bottleneck. Faster solutions likely require parallelism.

Answer (score 3):

Do you have about 350MB of RAM available? If so, you can try this function

```
rowequal <- function(x) {
  undetermined <- function(x, can_del) {
    if (length(can_del) < 1L)
      return(x)
    x[-can_del]
  }
  if (ncol(x) < 1L)
    return(logical())
  out <- logical(nrow(x))
  if (ncol(x) < 2L)
    return(!out)
  x1 <- x[[1L]]
  need_compare <- undetermined(seq_len(nrow(x)), which(x1 != x[[2L]]))
  x1[nas] <- x[[2L]][nas <- which(is.na(x1))]
  if (ncol(x) > 2L) {
    for (j in 3:ncol(x)) {
      need_compare <- undetermined(
        need_compare, which(x1[need_compare] != x[[j]][need_compare])
      )
      x1[nas] <- x[[j]][nas <- which(is.na(x1))]
      if (length(need_compare) < 1L)
        return(out)
    }
  }
  `[<-`(out, need_compare, TRUE)
}
```

Below is the benchmark

```
> dim(d)
[1] 3000000     300
> bench::mark(f(d), rowequal(d), iterations = 10)
# A tibble: 2 x 13
  expression       min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result memory time  gc   
  <bch:expr>  <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list> <list> <lis> <lis>
1 f(d)           2.97s    2.98s     0.335    34.4MB        0    10     0      29.8s <lgl ~ <Rpro~ <ben~ <tib~
2 rowequal(d)  88.52ms  93.34ms    10.7     352.2MB        0    10     0    932.5ms <lgl ~ <Rpro~ <ben~ <tib~
```

, where `f` (I got this from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70736403/10802499)) and `d` are

```
f <- function(x) {
  v1 = do.call(pmin, c(x, na.rm = TRUE))
  v2 = do.call(pmax, c(x, na.rm = TRUE))
  v1 == v2
}

mkDT <- function(rows, cols, type = as.integer) {
  data.table::setDT(
    replicate(cols, sample(type(c(1:10, NA)), rows, replace = TRUE), simplify = FALSE)
  )
}

d <- mkDT(3e6, 300)
```

---

An Rcpp version of the code. It could achieve its best performance (in terms of both memory usage and speed) if you can ensure that all the columns in your dataframe are of the `numeric` type. I guess this is the most efficient solution to your problem (in R).

```
rowequalcpp <- function(x) {
  if (ncol(x) < 1L)
    return(logical())
  out <- logical(nrow(x))
  if (ncol(x) < 2L)
    return(!out)
  mark_equal(out, x)
  out
}

Rcpp::sourceCpp(code = '
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void mark_equal(Rcpp::LogicalVector& res, const Rcpp::DataFrame& df) {
  Rcpp::NumericVector x1 = df[0];
  int n = df.nrows();
  int need_compare[n];
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    need_compare[i] = i;
  for (int j = 1; j < df.length(); ++j) {
    Rcpp::NumericVector dfj = df[j];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ) {
      int itmp = need_compare[i];
      if (Rcpp::NumericVector::is_na(x1[itmp]))
        x1[itmp] = dfj[itmp];
      if (!Rcpp::NumericVector::is_na(dfj[itmp]) && x1[itmp] != dfj[itmp]) {
        need_compare[i] = need_compare[n - 1];
        need_compare[n-- - 1] = itmp;
      } else
        ++i;
    }
    if (n < 1)
      return;
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    res[need_compare[i]] = TRUE;
}
')
```

Benchmark (the type of your columns are crucial for the  performance):

```
> d <- mkDT(3000000, 300, as.integer)
> bench::mark(rowequal(d), rowequalcpp(d), iterations = 10)
# A tibble: 2 x 13
  expression        min  median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result memory time  gc   
  <bch:expr>     <bch:> <bch:t>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list> <list> <lis> <lis>
1 rowequal(d)     100ms   147ms      7.07     398MB     3.03     7     3      991ms <lgl ~ <Rpro~ <ben~ <tib~
2 rowequalcpp(d)  101ms   102ms      9.35     309MB     2.34     8     2      855ms <lgl ~ <Rpro~ <ben~ <tib~
> d <- mkDT(3000000, 300, as.numeric)
> bench::mark(rowequal(d), rowequalcpp(d), iterations = 10)
# A tibble: 2 x 13
  expression          min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result  memory   time 
  <bch:expr>     <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list>  <list>   <lis>
1 rowequal(d)     103.7ms  110.8ms      8.05   349.3MB    0.895     9     1      1.12s <lgl [~ <Rprofm~ <ben~
2 rowequalcpp(d)   26.3ms   27.3ms     36.3     11.4MB    0        10     0    275.2ms <lgl [~ <Rprofm~ <ben~
# ... with 1 more variable: gc <list>
```

Comment: rowequal is about 18 seconds,  rowequalcpp is 1.9 seconds on my real data. rowequalcpp works fine for for the first row, but return false for other rows.

Comment: @هنروقتان Hi, there is a bug in the code. I have corrected it. Try the updated one.

Comment: thanks for your update, it produces the right answer, but the new version took 10.4 seconds. is it expected?

Comment: Interesting benchmarking result, upvoted!

Comment: @هنروقتان Yes. The old version skipped some operations unexpectedly. Also, based on your update, your columns are not all of the same numeric type. This makes the code slower cuz I wrote it based on that assumption. Perhaps it can be further optimized to account for this. But first, is it possible for you to convert the dataframe into all numerics?

Comment: changing columns type isn't doable, since other parts of workflow need data frame as it is, this part filter the bad observations and rest are pipe to the next step.

Comment: Hi, 1) may you explain why you need integers and numerics but check whether they are equal to each other? By this check, you implicitly mean they are of the same type. AFAIK, converting integers to numerics won't lead to numerically different results. 2) How much RAM do you have exactly? It seems to me that the performance bottleneck is reached because `gc` has to be called during the operation. 3) Are you measuring the performance correctly? Note that the part written in c++ should not be sourced like an R script every single time. You can reuse the DLL compiled to save time. @هنروقتان

Comment: algorithms down the road are optimized for integers (side note, I coerced all values to numeric and your code took 8 seconds/2 sec less). I am not including Rcpp compilation into account, and I use `system.time`, and my system has 32G of memory.

Comment: How many rows have the same values? I checked this algorithm again with 1e6 rows with identical values. It did slow down a lot since all entries in these rows need to be visited. @هنروقتان

Comment: 30-50% on average, occasionally up to 70%

Comment: I guess that's the bottleneck. You can hardly get any more improvement without parallelism since all those entries need to be visited before the program can decide if they are identical. That said, how many threads/cores do you have on your computer? @هنروقتان

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241191/discussion-between--and-ekoam).

Answer (score 2):

Structure matters. Here is a matrix approach in R, using the `matrixStats` package ([source](https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/matrixStats)), which ships optimized matrix functions implemented in C.

```r
x = sample.int(3, size = 303*3e6, replace = T)            
m = matrix(x, ncol = 303, byrow = T)
bench::mark(
  var = matrixStats::rowVars(m, na.rm = T) == 0
)
```

On my (certainly not high performance) machine this takes roughly 3.5 seconds for a 3 million row matrix.

Comment: but my data structure isn't really a matrix, and converting it to a matrix isn't very efficient.

Comment: In original post some answers showed up using `as.matrix`, however, this is not cost effective. remember `as.matrix` needs to make an extra copy of data frame.

Answer (score 0):

A quick update about this question,
I manage to reduce the time to about 2 seconds (less than 3 MiB memory usage!) using the following functions, no parallelism is used yet: (the magic is in using `@.`)

```
julia> f(x,y) = ismissing(x) || ismissing(y) ? true : x == y

julia> function rowequal(df, cols)
           res=ones(Bool, nrow(df))
           for i in 2:length(cols)
               @. res &= ifelse(f(df[!, cols[i-1]], df[!,cols[i]]), true, false)
           end
           res
       end
```

Answer (score -3):

I suggest you to use `python`, it has two great products for this, `pandas` the most popular data frame library and `polars` the fastest data frame library in the world! ([db-benchmark](https://h2oai.github.io/db-benchmark/)).

```py
import time
t1=time.time();df.max(axis=1)==df.min(axis=1);t2=time.time()
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I am aware of `pandas` and `polars`. They are good products, no doubt, but, the exact website you mentioned in your post, suggests that I shouldn't use `pandas` if performance is the high priority and I shouldn't use `polars` if efficiency is the high priority, AND, I should use `data.table` if I am looking for speed and efficiency! PS your answer took about 6 seconds, but I am not sure `pandas` is as good as this for the rest of workflow. `polars` took 28 seconds.